# How to read lines from a variable | bash

Tags: bash, text-processing, files, scripting

I have a simple bash script that reads lines from a text file like so:

```
#!/bin/bash
FILE=$1
while read line; do
...
done < $FILE
```

which works fine but now I want to first parse the file using grep like so :

```
INPUT_file=$(grep -E 'INPUT.*ACCEPT' $FILE)
```

and then assign that result to the variable INPUT_file

I would like to now read lines from the variable "INPUT_file" but when I try to include in the while loop:

```
while read line; do
....
done < $INPUT_file
```

I get the following error:

```
$INPUT_file: ambiguous redirect
```

Comment: Related: [Why is using a shell loop to process text considered bad practice?](//unix.stackexchange.com/q/169716)

Comment: And: [Understand "IFS= read -r line"?](//unix.stackexchange.com/q/209123)

Answer (score 2):

You would be better off using [process substitution](https://www.gnu.org/software/bash/manual/bashref.html#Process-Substitution) rather than a variable:

```
while read line; do
....
done < <(grep -E 'INPUT.*ACCEPT' $FILE)
```

(note two `<` characters). This avoids loading the entire `grep` output into memory at once to store in a variable. The `grep` process will be run in parallel with the loop, and the loop will see `grep`'s output as `read`'s input as each line prints out (up to buffering).

This will tend to be faster and use less memory than using `$(...)` command substitution and keeping the whole output around. It's also generally better style if you're writing a Bash-specific script, because it's explicit about what you're using the command for.

---

Arguably, this is a bit of an antipattern to start with - you might be better still using an ordinary pipeline for whatever processing you require, rather than `while read ...` and processing it in Bash, but there are valid cases for using either.

Answer (score 0):

That is when [here string](https://bash.cyberciti.biz/guide/Here_strings) comes into play:

```
while read line; do
...
done<<<$INPUT_file
```

Comment: this didn't work for me as it now treated INPUT_FILE as an empty file, for example if I placed a echo "$line" in the while loop, it would print nothing

Answer (score 0):

You shouldn't invoke `grep` in this case. All can be done using your shell only. E.g

```
while read -r line; do [[ $line =~ INPUT.*ACCEPT ]] && printf '%s\n' "$line"; done < your_iptables_file
```